# Iterate through array, use content as file output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I am having a problem, I am sure it is something very simple that I am over looking but, I can not seem to see it.

So I am trying to loop through an Array, Do some with using the content of each element and then using the element as a file to redirect too.

```
fullProc=$(grep "WNDP_Server" $1 | grep -v "#" | cut -f 2  | grep -v /nwsys/release/conf/save" | cut -d '/' -f5)
for i in "${fullProc[@]}"
do
   echo "$host$HostName" > "$i"
   grep "WNDP_Server: * " $1 | grep -v "#" | cut -f 2-3 | grep -v "/nwsys/release/conf/save" | grep -w "$i" | cut -f 2 >> "$i"
   grep "WNDP_Port:" $1 | grep -v "#" | grep -w "$i" | cut -f 3 >> "$i"
   ProcName=$(grep "WNDP_Server: * " $1 | grep -v "#" | cut -f 2  | grep -v "/nwsys/release/conf/save" | cut -d '/' -f5 | grep -w "$i" | cut -d '.' -f1)
   echo "Process: $ProcName" >> "$i"
   grep -w "FilterMode:" $1 | grep -v "#" | cut -f 2-3 | grep -w "$i" | cut -f2 >> "$i"
   grep -w "Filter:" $1 | grep -v "#" | cut -f 2-3 | grep -w "$i" | cut -f2 >> "$i"
done
```

What I get is a single file with all the correct information. instead of multiple files each with their corresponding information.

If you need me to clarify this please let me know.

$i is the file name in question.

Comment: Show you sample input and output.

Comment: What are the multiple files you want to get?

Comment: For example $fullProc=( xprofd.cfg , xprofd.cfg2 ). So i am trying to fill xprofd.cfg with certain information, and loop to xprofd.cfg2 and fill it with its own information

Comment: Please include the code *in your post* that sets the value of `fullProc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign `fullProc` like this:

```
fullProc=($(grep ...))
```

Notice the extra `(...)` around the `$(grep ...)`.

Otherwise all the matches of `grep` will be in a single string.